# Count Overlap Between Neighboring Indices in NumPy Array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array of integers:

```
x = np.array([1, 0, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 0, 1, 4, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 4, 1, 0])
```

and another array of indices that references the array above:

```
indices = np.array([22, 12, 8, 1, 14, 21, 7, 0, 13, 19, 5, 3, 9, 16, 2, 15, 11, 18, 20, 6, 4, 10, 17])
```

For every pair of neighboring indices, we need to count how many consecutive values in `x` are overlapping starting at each of the two neighboring indices. For example, for `indices[2]` and `indices[3]`, we have index `8` and `1`, respectively, and they both reference positions in `x`. Then, starting at `x[8]` and `x[1]`, we count how many consecutive values are the same or are overlapping but we stop checking the overlap under specific conditions (see below). In other words, we check if:

1. `x[8] == x[1]`
2. `x[9] == x[2]`  # increment each index by one
3. ...  # continue incrementing each index except in the following conditions
4. stop if  `i >= x.shape[0]`
5. stop if  `j >= x.shape[0]`

<s>6. stop if `x[i] == 0`</s>
<s>7. stop if `x[j] == 0`</s>

8. stop if `x[i] != x[j]`

In reality, we do this for all neighboring index pairs:

```
out = np.zeros(indices.shape[0], dtype=int)
for idx in range(indices.shape[0]-1):
    count = 0
    i = indices[idx]
    j = indices[idx + 1]
    k = 0
    # while i+k < x.shape[0] and j+k < x.shape[0] and x[i+k] != 0 and x[j+k] != 0 and x[i+k] == x[j+k]:
    while i+k < x.shape[0] and j+k < x.shape[0] and x[i+k] == x[j+k]:
        count += 1
        k += 1
        out[idx] = k
```

And the output is:

```
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0]  # This is the old output if x[i] == 0 and x[j] == 0 are included

[1 2 1 4 0 2 2 5 1 4 3 2 3 0 3 0 1 0 3 2 1 2 0]
```

I'm looking for a vectorized way to do this in NumPy.

Comment: What's the reason for vectorizing your working code with loop? How big is your x?

Comment: `x` may be in the billions or longer

Comment: I tried your code with numba.jit, and for x of length 10^8 it took me couple of seconds to run. If your x has billions of elements then I don't think that numpy's vectorized version (even if you find it) will be able to beat jit here.

Comment: @AndreasK. I'm actually using Numba right now but I am trying to remove it as a dependency. So, I understand that I'll take a hit on performance but, with a pure NumPy implementation, I hope to be faster than CPython and slower than Numba. Right now, it's the while loop conditions that's a tricky part. If it helps, you can ignore the two conditions `x[i] == 0` and `x[j] == 0`

Comment: In your example, why is the result 0? `x[8:]` is `[0,1,4,3...]` and `x[1:] is [0,2,1,4...]`, so there's an overlap of 1.

Comment: That is the case when `x[i] == 0` and `x[j] == 0` are not included. I've updated the output to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (I am ignoring the two conditions `x[i]=0` and `x[j]=0`)

```py
for idx in range(indices.shape[0]-1):

    i = indices[idx]
    j = indices[idx + 1]

    l = len(x) - max(i,j)
    x1 = x[i:i+l]
    x2 = x[j:j+l]

    # Add False at the end to handle the case in which arrays are exactly the same
    x0 = np.append(x1==x2, False)

    out[idx] = np.argmin(x0)
```

Notice that with `np.argmin` I am exploiting the following two facts:

- `False < True`
- `np.argmin` only returns the first instance of the min in the array

#### Performance Analysis

Regarding time performance, I tested with `N=10**5` and `N=10**6`, and as suggested in the comments, this cannot compete with numba jit.

```py
def f(x, indices):

    out = np.zeros(indices.shape[0], dtype=int)

    for idx in range(indices.shape[0]-1):

        i = indices[idx]
        j = indices[idx + 1]

        l = len(x) - max(i,j)
        x1 = x[i:i+l]
        x2 = x[j:j+l]

        x0 = np.append(x1==x2, False)

        out[idx] = np.argmin(x0)

    return out

N=100_000
x = np.random.randint(0,10, N)
indices = np.arange(0, N)
np.random.shuffle(indices)

%timeit f(x, indices)
3.67 s ± 122 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

N=1_000_000
x = np.random.randint(0,10, N)
indices = np.arange(0, N)
np.random.shuffle(indices)

%time f(x, indices)
Wall time: 8min 20s
```

(I did not have the patience to let `%timeit` finish)